# PHP setting numbers automatically

Tags: php

```
<?php 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE tag='sports'"); 
    $strss=$strss+1;
         while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
             {
         echo '<li id="nav'.$strss.'"><a href="#" >'.$row['title'].'</li>';
             }
?>
```

Why can't I set numbers automatically? the number always is `1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to move your counter inside the while loop like the following:

```
<?php 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE tag='sports'"); 
    $strss=1;
         while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
             {
                 echo '<li id="nav'.$strss.'"><a href="#" >'.$row['title'].'</li>';
                 $strss++;
             }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad I have known this today.

Answer (score 1):

Because the increment is outside the loop.